# How to average values base on different row indexes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which has multiIndex rows and multiIndex columns.

[image]

I would like to average the values of every column, base on the value of the multiIndex b and c.

Then these values to be saved in new columns which have a new level of column index with the name of the index based on which it has been averaged ( in this case "b" and "c")

Something like that:

[image]

In the original columns, just add a level column name equal to the first row index name which has not been used ( in this case "a")

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Colourful pictures are nice, but not as helpful. Can you please provide a [mcve] that has your data as text so it can be pasted into an interpreter easily?

Comment: I do dig the pictures (what did you use to make them?) but coldspeed is completely correct: they're not helpful for figuring out your problem. Even if you just run `print(df)` and paste the output into the question, that would be much easier to work with than figures.

Comment: Maybe something like `pd.concat([df.groupby(level=[1,2])[col].transform('mean') for col in df.columns],1)` might help. But as the other comments say we need to check on the data so need the text version of it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. These are sample tables from excel. If I paste them, they come as pictures. Is there a way to paste data from excel?